# oracle stored procedure updating one table with the help of another table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
TABLE A  : name empid activeind 
TABLE B  : name empid activeind
```

update table A based on table B comparing `empid` from both the table using Oracle stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option.

```
create or replace procedure p_upd is
begin
  merge into a
  using b
  on (b.empid = a.empid)
  when matched then update set a.name = b.name,
                               a.activeind = b.activeind;
end;
/
```

---

**[EDIT]** Based on your comment: you used wrong syntax. `UPDATE` should be

```
UPDATE a
   SET (a.name, a.activeind) =
          (SELECT b.name, b.activeind
             FROM b
            WHERE b.empid = a.empid)
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT NULL
             FROM b
            WHERE b.empid = a.empid);
```

Why `exists`? Without it, you'd set `name` and `activeid` values to `null` for all `a.empid` rows that don't exist in `b` table.

Comment: THANKS      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateTableA

IS 
BEGIN 

UPDATE
  TABLEA SET   NAME = TABLEB_NAME 
                            ACTIVEIND = TABLEB_ACTIVEIND
          where EMPID = TABLEB_EMPID ;

COMMIT ; 

END ; 
  
/      I was trying this what I was doing wrong

Comment: Wrong syntax. I posted some more info in the answer; have a look.